# Is there a way to bind click events to buttons in schemas?

Tags: vue-formulate

Is there a way to make my schema accept click events for buttons, or do click events have to be binded manually?

For example, is there a way to do something like

```
schema: [
    {
      type: 'button',
      name: 'sample-button',
      label: 'Here is a button',
      click: myClickFunction(),
    }
  ]
```

or do I have to manually set a FormulateInput element and put this in my template

```
<FormulateInput
   type="button"
   name="Here is a button"
   @click="myClickFunction()"
/>
```